# what's the difference between while using `let` in switch case at begin or in the()

Tags: swift

I have a little doubt about the `let position` in switch case, here is a simple code, which one is better

```swift
enum Result{
    case success(code:Int)
    case fail(err:NSError)
}

var result = Result.success(code: 3)

switch result {
case  .success(let code):// first
case let .success(code)://second
    print("success",code)
default:
    print("fail")
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`case  .success(let code):`

This syntax is used when the `enum` specifies the `let` value. In this case, `enum Result` specifies that the `case success` will also include an `Int` value for `code`.

Using `let` right after `case` in a switch statement is generally used in conjunction with a `where` clause to allow for more complex `case` values in a switch statement. An example of such could be as below

```
var text = "Hello"
var greetings = ["Hello", "Good Bye"]

switch text {
case let value where greetings.contains(value):
    print("Yes")
default:
    print("No")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As [The Swift Programming Language: Enumeration: Associated Values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148) says:

> You can check the different barcode types using a `switch` statement, similar to the example in [Matching Enumeration Values with a Switch Statement](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID147). This time, however, the associated values are extracted as part of the switch statement. You extract each associated value as a constant (with the `let` prefix) or a variable (with the `var` prefix) for use within the `switch` case’s body:
>
> ```
> switch productBarcode {
> case .upc(let numberSystem, let manufacturer, let product, let check):
>     print("UPC: \(numberSystem), \(manufacturer), \(product), \(check).")
> case .qrCode(let productCode):
>     print("QR code: \(productCode).")
> }
> // Prints "QR code: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP."
> ```
>
> If all of the associated values for an enumeration case are extracted as constants, or if all are extracted as variables, you can place a single `var` or `let` annotation before the case name, for brevity:
>
> ```
> switch productBarcode {
> case let .upc(numberSystem, manufacturer, product, check):
>     print("UPC : \(numberSystem), \(manufacturer), \(product), \(check).")
> case let .qrCode(productCode):
>     print("QR code: \(productCode).")
> }
> // Prints "QR code: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP."
> ```

In short, they’re equivalent, and the latter is a useful shorthand when you are extracting more than one associated value.

Answer (score 1):

```
case .success(let code):// first
case let .success(code)://second
```

In the examples as you have shown them, there is no difference. Both are legal, and both do the same thing. They are equivalent patterns in this context.